# как объединять объекты с разными модификаторами в блендер, с возможностью дальнейшего редактирования каждого из модификаторов

Tags: blender

Допустим есть дерево. Его кроне применён модификатор Subdivision Surface. Крону нужно объединить со стволом (именно через ctrl j). У ствола нет модификаторов.
Как объединить их в один объект (потому что потом нужно производить манипуляции со всем деревом), но при этом сохранить возможность применять разны модификаторы к этим двум частям, а также редактировать после объединения уже имеющиеся (Subdivision Surface в данном случае)?
Где-то писали применить Apply модификатор и после объединять. Но как тогда его редактировать после применения??
И что делать, если я хочу объединить объекты в один, но иметь возможность накладывать к разным его частям разные модификаторы?
P.S: занимаюсь 3д недавно, поэтому может вопрос банальный, но найти ответ всё никак не могу. Плюс ко всему, в обучающем видео, по которому я делаю сцену, почему-то этой проблемы нет. Автор объединяет через ctrl j без предварительного применения Apply, указывая последним объектом ствол (который без модификаторов вообще), но с кроны при этом модификатор у него не слетает. У меня же при тех же действиях слетает с кроны Subdivision Surface
Видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wkIyzaA5pMk, тайминг 18:50

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста ссылку на видео желательно с таймингом, если есть возможность, если у Вас не получилось повторить, это либо монтированное видео либо что-то упустили. Я могу посмотреть только на версии 2.79 - уменя модификатор применяется к 2 объектам тогда, либо слетает с первого

Comment: Ссылки удобнее делать с таймингом) Насколько я вижу, по видео, по-моему раньше делал этот урок, то там `solidify` модификатор причем внутрь, поэтому даже если он на столб перескакивает он не виден, ну а еще [тут 20:33](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wkIyzaA5pMk&t=1233) видно что и не было объединения.

Comment: @DaniilLoban Мод-ор делала тоже внутрь (да, перепутала солидивай и сабдивижн, упсс)) ). Но автор указал, что последним объектом выделяем именно ствол, а так как он последний, то моды именно с него наследовались на всё дерево. Что в итоге приводило к слёту мода с кроны. Главный вопрос конечно был, почему у автора вообще получилась эта чёрная магия, а у меня всё сбивалось при тех же действиях.. Теперь ещё и вопрос, почему на 20:33 объединения не было, не замечала этого раньше. На несколько загадок во вселенной больше) Сделаю также теперь. До этого просто применяла мод до объединения.
Спасибо!

Comment: Возможно он монтировал видео, но вообще-то я не замечал чтобы он их объединял, а что говорил не слушал особо, но вроде речь шла про ветки только)